# GraphDB Custom Ruleset Fails to Compile: code too large

Tags: graphdb

I'm using a custom ruleset in one of my repositories in GraphDB, but when I try to create the repository, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: com.ontotext.trree.rules.RuleCompilerException: code too large
```

(see below for entire error log).

Does this mean there is a limit on the number of lines you are allowed to have in a rule file?

```
org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.ServerHTTPException: org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.RepositoryException: org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.SailException: Invalid rule set: /opt/graphdb/home/rules/rules-ontology-processor.pie
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.repository.RepositoryInterceptor.setRequestAttributes(RepositoryInterceptor.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.ServerInterceptor.preHandle(ServerInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.repository.RepositoryInterceptor.preHandle(RepositoryInterceptor.java:82)
    at com.ontotext.forest.sesame.ForestRepositoryInterceptor.preHandle(ForestRepositoryInterceptor.java:32)
    at com.ontotext.forest.sesame.ForestRepositoryInterceptor$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d99bcd9f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.ontotext.forest.sesame.ForestRepositoryInterceptor$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f80e69e5.preHandle(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.ontotext.forest.core.request.RequestFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestFilter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.github.ziplet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.ontotext.forest.security.AdminDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(AdminDelegatingFilterProxy.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.RepositoryException: org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.SailException: Invalid rule set: /opt/graphdb/home/rules/rules-ontology-processor.pie
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.SailRepository.initializeInternal(SailRepository.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.base.AbstractRepository.init(AbstractRepository.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.manager.LocalRepositoryManager.createRepository(LocalRepositoryManager.java:258)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.GraphDBRepositoryManager.createRepository(GraphDBRepositoryManager.java:380)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.GraphDBRepositoryManager$FutureRepository.lambda$new$0(GraphDBRepositoryManager.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.GraphDBRepositoryManager.awaitFutureRepository(GraphDBRepositoryManager.java:795)
    at com.ontotext.graphdb.GraphDBRepositoryManager.getRepository(GraphDBRepositoryManager.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.repository.RepositoryInterceptor.setRequestAttributes(RepositoryInterceptor.java:105)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.SailException: org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.SailException: Invalid rule set: /opt/graphdb/home/rules/rules-ontology-processor.pie
    at com.ontotext.trree.OwlimSchemaRepository.initializeInternal(OwlimSchemaRepository.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.helpers.AbstractSail.init(AbstractSail.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.SailRepository.initializeInternal(SailRepository.java:146)
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.SailException: Invalid rule set: /opt/graphdb/home/rules/rules-ontology-processor.pie
    at com.ontotext.trree.OwlimSchemaRepository.createInferencer(OwlimSchemaRepository.java:1566)
    at com.ontotext.trree.OwlimSchemaRepository.initializeInternal(OwlimSchemaRepository.java:207)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ontotext.trree.rules.RuleCompilerException: code too large
    at com.ontotext.trree.rules.RuntimeInferencerCompilerBase.compileSource(RuntimeInferencerCompilerBase.java:79)
    at com.ontotext.trree.rules.RuntimeInferencerCompiler.compileInferencer(RuntimeInferencerCompiler.java:57)
    at com.ontotext.trree.OwlimSchemaRepository.createInferencer(OwlimSchemaRepository.java:1561)
    ... 67 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The rule compiler generates Java code out of the PIE file and then compiles it. So, there is a limit imposed by the JVM to the size of the class filed references and number of methods (up to 64k for each). The practical limit of the ruleset size is around 6000-8000 rules (depends their on cmplexity)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I checked and my ruleset has 45 individual rules. A few rules have a large number of lines in body and head (up to 18 lines in each). Could that be causing the problem?